# Change zoom rate on different breakpoint for embed google my map

Tags: google-maps

I need to change zoom rate on different breakpoint for embed google my map. Map is embed in `iframe` like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=ID_here&z=15" width="100%"></iframe>
```

As you can see, zoom is 15, but I need to change it on mobile and tablet devices.

Do you have idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>test</title></head>
  <body>
    <iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBu9SPYB9qp2PTe1M1_TyBAQN4c-yL8HYQ
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA&zoom=10" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
    <script>
        function setEmbeddedMapZoom() {
            var zoomForPhone = 15;
            var defaultZoom = 10;
            var baseSrc = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA&zoom=';
            if (window.innerWidth < 1600) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute('src', baseSrc + zoomForPhone);
            } else {
                document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute('src', baseSrc + defaultZoom);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', setEmbeddedMapZoom);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/tucanayiye/edit?html,output

Please note that I had to make sure the Embed API was turned on in the project where I created the API key.